# Воспроизведение аудио (mp3) как потока

Tags: потоки-данных, radio, web-audio, playerjs

Существует ли возможность трансляции аудио в браузер без загрузки самого файла на Web Audio API (без icecast итп). Например загрузка потока в буфер и воспроизведение. Требуется чтоб файл нельзя было скачать (скрыть путь). В конечном итоге должен получится простой плеер для продажи аудио. Может какая простенькая лайбрари JS,PHP?